# checking existence of objects before merging

Tags: r, boolean-logic

I wonder if there is a better way of checking existence of objects (lists of data.frames), before merging,
in my approach each possibility is tested.

```
if(exists("list1") & exists("list2") &  exists("list3") ) {
  consolidateDF <- dplyr::bind_rows(list3,list1,list2, .id = "column1")
} else if (exists("list1") & exists("list2") ) {
  consolidateDF <- dplyr::bind_rows(list1,list2, .id = "column1")
} else if (exists("list1") & exists("list3") ) {
  consolidateDF <- dplyr::bind_rows(list1,list3, .id = "column1")
} else if (exists("list3") & exists("list2") ) {
  consolidateDF <- dplyr::bind_rows(list3,list2, .id = "column1")
} else if (exists("list3") ) {
  consolidateDF <- dplyr::bind_rows(list3, .id = "column1")
} else if (exists("list2") ) {
  consolidateDF <- dplyr::bind_rows(list2, .id = "column1")
} else if (exists("list1") ) {
  consolidateDF <- dplyr::bind_rows(list1, .id = "column1")
}
```

another try (not working, gets only one list)

```
dplyr::bind_rows(eval(parse(text=ls(pattern="list") ) ) , .id="column")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner using `mget/ls`:

```
dplyr::bind_rows(mget(ls(pattern = "^list", envir = .GlobalEnv), envir = .GlobalEnv), .id = "column1")
#   column1 x
#1    list1 1
#2    list1 2
#3    list1 3
#4    list1 4
#5    list1 5
#6    list3 1
#7    list3 2
#8    list3 3
#9    list3 4
#10   list3 5
```

Breaking down this code, note that the `envir` in `ls` and in `mget` must be the same.

```
df_names <- ls(pattern = "^list", envir = .GlobalEnv)
dplyr::bind_rows(mget(df_names, envir = .GlobalEnv), .id = "column1")
```

**Test data**

```
set.seed(2020)
df_list <- lapply(1:4, function(i){
  if(runif(1) > 0.5) data.frame(x = 1:5)
})
names(df_list) <- paste0("list", 1:4)
df_list <- df_list[!sapply(df_list, is.null)]

list2env(df_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: what should i use to make it work inside a function (package), envir?

Comment: @Ferroao Both `ls` and `mget` have an argument `envir`. In the case above I only set one of them but in a function you should set both. If the data sets are in the global environment, as is most often the case, then set `envir = .GlobalEnv`. Note that in the test data creation code, I create the df's in the `.GlobalEnv`, so `ls` and `mget` will find them there.

Comment: data.sets will be internal only, not global

Comment: @Ferroao The `envir` argument is where the data can be found. Have you read Hadley Whickham's [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html) on this?

Comment: @Ferroao Yes, that's the data in the question, right? `mget` puts them in a list (of df's) before rbinding them all.

Comment: you call "list" a data.frame. seems odd. I will try not to work with data.frames. i think it is not necessary. I wil try to stick to lists of them.

Comment: i mean, it is not necessary, dplyr manage lists

Comment: @Ferroao OK, I admit to have posted a confusing test data set. But the main point stands, check for existence (in a certain environment) with `ls`, passing a regex matching the lists' names in `pattern`. Then `mget` them all and bind them together in one operation .